# PLSQL - Merge table variables

Tags: database, plsql, multiset

I have a function Func_A which returns a table variable. Now I want to create an other function Func_B which calls Func_A multiple times and returns all the results of Func_A combined. But only the last result of Func_A is returned. How to merge all the results of function a together?

```
CREATE TYPE RowType AS OBJECT (ItemNumber int, ItemName varchar2(255));
/
CREATE TYPE TableType AS TABLE OF RowType;
/

create or replace
FUNCTION Func_A (v_test int)
RETURN TableType AS 
v_result TableType := TableType();
BEGIN  
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
    v_result.extend;
    v_result(v_result.last) := RowType(i * v_test, 'Blub');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_result;
END;

create or replace
FUNCTION Func_B
RETURN TableType AS 
v_result TableType := TableType();
BEGIN  
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
    SELECT cast(multiset (select * FROM TABLE(Func_A(i))) as TableType)
    INTO v_result
    FROM DUAL;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_result;
END;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(Func_B())
```

This should be the most efficient way:

```
v_result := Func_A(i) MULTISET UNION ALL v_result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In every loop iteration you overwrite `v_result` with the latest result set from `Func_A`. Instead use `union` to append the iteration's result to previous iterations' results.

```
FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
  SELECT cast(multiset (select * FROM TABLE(Func_A(i))) as TableType)
         multiset union all v_result
    INTO v_result
    FROM DUAL;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Is this the most efficient method or are there other possibilities merging to table variables together?

Comment: @user2798190 AFAIK yes - it is. I see you found the simpler syntax by yourself. See also [Assigning Set Operation Results to Nested Table Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm#CIHIHEHG) from Oracle docs.